# Undefined symbols: "_OBJC_CLASS_$ error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, linker

I've been looking through countless posts about this error:

```
Undefined symbols:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BoxView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-BoxView in ViewMovingViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`BoxView` is a subclass of `UIView`, and the `UIKit` framework has been included. `BoxView.h` has been imported in the ViewController.

The ViewController contains this code:

```
-(void) addBoxViewAtLocation:(CGPoint)point {
    CGRect rect;  
    rect.origin.x = point.x;  
    rect.origin.y = point.y;  
    rect.size.width = 80;  
    rect.size.width = 40;  
    BoxView *newView = [[BoxView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];  
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];  
    [mainView addSubview:newView];  
}
```

And `BoxView` contains this code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {     
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];  
    if (self) {  
        // no further initialization  
    }  
    return self; 
}
```

This is the line that's causing the error, from the code above:

```
BoxView *newView = [[BoxView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
```

When I change `BoxView` to `UIView` in that line, the error goes away. Does anyone know what I need to change here? I have looked through many posts about this, but most answers say it's link related, but I've tried ticking and unticking certain boxes with no success. I'm wondering if the error is in my code? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 54):

In general, this will occur when the code for `BoxView` is not being compiled into your target correctly.

[image: identity editor screenshot]

You need to ensure that the target you're building has its corresponding box checked for your `BoxView.m` implementation file. Your question suggests that you've tried this, but here's a screenshot (from Xcode 4) just for clarity's sake.

A 'Clean and Build' never hurts, either.

Comment: Thank you, definitely tried the clean build but haven't come across a tick box for BoxView.m .. Where would I find that tickbox? I'm looking through the Build settings but don't see it.. I'm working with an older version of X-Code, X-Code 3, so I don't think my version conforms to the screenshot you sent

Comment: Oh actually, I just found it. Don't know if its the case in Xcode 4 but in Xcode 3 you can literally drag and drop the .m file into the target

Comment: Sometimes when I add files to projects they are not compiled when the project is built. In Xcode 4, I explicitly add them under "Build Phases" -> "Compile Sources". Why these are not set (sometimes) by default, I don't know.

Comment: @cms If this did solve (or help with) your problem, it would be great if you could accept the answer. :-)

Comment: I can't tell how you made my day with this answer. Thanks a lot for sharing the knowledge.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't want to claim that I now understand all the ins and outs of this problem, but hey, I can compile my app!

Comment: I got this error because I defined a class in a header file, without any ```@implementation```. Adding an empty ```@implementation``` into the .m solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add that Ben Mosher's answer is totally right. But there's another way to include the files to build in the Target settings.

[image]

Comment: works in Xcode 7 very similarly but you access `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` from the `General` tab for a given selected target.

Answer (score 1):

**Added Scenario**

If your project has module dependencies(framework), rebuild them before building your main project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
In my case, it was a problem caused by LFS.

1. Open the Terminal application.
2. Install Git-LFS.

   brew install git-lfs
3. Enter this command for initialization after LFS install was completed.

   git-lfs install

4-1. (If you use CocoaPods) Move to project folder, and reinstall Pods(remove -> install).

4-2. (If you not use CocoaPods) Remove clone, and download it again.